# Pact consumer tests in angular and HttpIntercepter

Tags: karma-runner, pact

Our application uses HttpInterceptor to convert JSON properties from camel-case to snake-case.

I configure pact in karma.conf.js and set pact proxy there.

For my test I use TestBed:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpClientModule
        ],
        providers: [
            EmployeeService,
            { provide: SERVER_URLS, useValue: TokenPactMock.SERVER_URLS() },
            { provide: HTTP_RETRY_ATTEMPTS, useValue: TokenMock.HTTP_RETRY_ATTEMPTS() }
        ],
    });
```

and this is my test:

```
const employeeService: EmployeeService = TestBed.get(EmployeeServiceService);
         employeeService.addEmployee(employee).subscribe(response => {
            expect(response.status).toEqual(201);
            expect(response.body).toEqual(employee);
            done();
        }, error => {
            done.fail(error);
        });
```

This test runs successfully and pact file is generated. But HttpInterceptor was not trigger and in PACT file I have camel-case properties instead of snake-case.

Does anybody know how to use PACT with HttpInterceptor?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular, but if you could share a repository with a repro we can take a look.

Comment: Could you please post the code you have for HTTPInterceptor?  I know a lot about angular and how that works, but I'm guessing it's not being using during tests, probably because someone wanted to test out the transform in the interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

We have found the answer. It was our misunderstanding of difference between HttpClientModule and HttpClientTestingModule.

In HttpClientModule we must explicitly define our listeners:

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [
        EmployeeService,
        { provide: SERVER_URLS, useValue: TokenPactMock.SERVER_URLS() },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpNamingInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_RETRY_ATTEMPTS, useValue: TokenMock.HTTP_RETRY_ATTEMPTS() }
    ],
});
```